# route line does not appear using MkMap in xamarin ios

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

i want to draw route line using mkMap in xamarin ios. my code is working correctly but it does not show route line between points. my code is given below
my first picture shows the starting annotation point and second picture shows ending annotation point

***MapView Code:***

```
 private MKMapView _map;
       private  MapDelegate _mapDelegate;

    public QiblaCompassVC (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        _map = new MKMapView(mapsView.Bounds)
        {
            MapType = MKMapType.Standard,
            ShowsUserLocation = true,
            ZoomEnabled = true,
            ScrollEnabled = true
        };
        //_map = new MKMapView(mapsView.Bounds);
       // _map.ShowsUserLocation = true;
        _mapDelegate = new MapDelegate();
        _map.Delegate = _mapDelegate;
         //mapsView.Add(_map);
        View = _map;
        var target = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(30.3753, 69.3451);
        var viewPoint = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(21.3891, 39.8579);
        var annotation = new mapAnnotation(new CLLocationCoordinate2D(30.3753, 69.3451), "Pakistan", "Countery of love");
        _map.AddAnnotation(annotation);
        var annotation1 = new mapAnnotation(new CLLocationCoordinate2D(21.3891, 39.8579), "Makka", "Allah home");
        _map.AddAnnotation(annotation1);
        var camera = MKMapCamera.CameraLookingAtCenterCoordinate(target, viewPoint, 500);
        _map.Camera = camera;
        createRoute();
        //CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(30.3753, 69.3451);
        //MKCoordinateSpan span = new MKCoordinateSpan(MilesToLatitudeDegrees(20), MilesToLongitudeDegrees(20, coords.Latitude));
        //_map.Region = new MKCoordinateRegion(coords, span);
    }

    public void createRoute()
     {

        var dict = new NSDictionary();
        var orignPlaceMark = new MKPlacemark(new CLLocationCoordinate2D(30.3753, 69.3451), dict);
        var sourceItem = new MKMapItem(orignPlaceMark);

        //End at Xamarin Cambridge Office
        var destPlaceMark = new MKPlacemark(new CLLocationCoordinate2D(21.3891, 39.8579), dict);
        var destItem = new MKMapItem(destPlaceMark);

        var request = new MKDirectionsRequest
        {
            Source = sourceItem,
            Destination = destItem,
            RequestsAlternateRoutes = true,

        };

        var directions = new MKDirections(request);

        directions.CalculateDirections((response, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.LocalizedDescription);
            }
            else
            {
                //Add each Polyline from route to map as overlay
                foreach (var route in response.Routes)
                {
                    _map.AddOverlay(route.Polyline);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

***MapDelegate Code:***

```
class MapDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
    {
        public override MKOverlayRenderer OverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
        {
            if (overlay is MKPolyline)
            {
                var route = (MKPolyline)overlay;
                var renderer = new MKPolylineRenderer(route) { StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue };
                return renderer;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public override MKOverlayView GetViewForOverlay(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
        {
            if (overlay is MKPolyline)
            {
                // return a view for the polygon
                MKPolyline l_polyline = overlay as MKPolyline;
                MKPolylineView l_polylineView = new MKPolylineView(l_polyline);
                MKPolylineRenderer l_polylineRenderer = new MKPolylineRenderer(l_polyline);

                l_polylineView.FillColor = UIColor.Blue;
                l_polylineView.StrokeColor = UIColor.Red;

                return l_polylineView;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

[image: First pic is the Starting point]
[image: Second pic is ending point]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the **GetViewForOverlay** method,

The *overlay* parameter is not not of type **MKPolyline**, it is a wrapper containing the MKPolyline, this is how to get it :

```
MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
{
    var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;

    ...
}
```

[Source from xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61096/adding-a-polyline-overlay-to-a-map)